# require() function with an object param?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking at a require() function that looks like this and I have no clue what it does. It seems like it gets an array of files and builds a string of some try-catch blocks with interpolated module names, but I'm a bit hazy on the specifics.

```
require('./modules/**/index.js', {mode: (base, files) => {
    return files.map(module => {
        return `
            try {
                require('${module}');
            } catch (e) {
                debug.error('Failed to ${module}', e.stack);
            }
        `;
    }).join(' ');
}});
```

I looked for params in the Node documentation (https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) and couldn't find anything. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's a native `require`? Maybe there's smth before like `const require = require('my-custom-require')`?

Comment: It seems to be just a regular require(). Here's the full file in case I'm missing something: https://github.com/night/betterttv/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: Yes, missing  It's `require-globify` package set as dependancy in package.json and is used in gulpfile.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a regular require.

It's a [`require-globify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-globify) package. It allows globbing expressions to require. `mode` key of second parameter defines how to handle the calls.